# How to display featured or new products on main Ubercart catalog page?

Tags: ubercart

I'm having a little difficulty setting up Ubercart that may be related to the particular way I am wanting to use it. I'm sure I've just missed a setting somewhere or something.

I have the front page of my website at mysite.com, and the store located at mysite.com/store. I have added categories to the catalog taxonomy (mysite.com/store/category1). So the store is secondary to the front page.

When I go to mysite.com/store Ubercart only displays a list of the categories, and not any products (as expected, they are all within their categories). My issue though, is I would like to display some "new" or "featured" products on the mysite.com/store page instead of just the list of categories. If my store was located at mysite.com I could just use the "promoted to front page" option, but it is not.

How can I display products on mysite.com/store?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view and make a block in that and then expose that on the /store page above your content or what you see fit. that should do it.